# Redhat Linux 6.5 Perl GD CPAN Module yum

Tags: perl, gd, redhat, cpan, yum

when i try to install "GD" (perl -e shell -MCPAN ->(next step) cpan[1]> install GD) on Redhat 6.5 i got the error:

->
 CPAN.pm: Building L/LD/LDS/GD-2.53.tar.gz

**UNRECOVERABLE ERROR**
Could not find gdlib-config in the search path. Please install libgd 2.0.28 or higher.
If you want to try to compile anyway, please rerun this script with the option --ignore_missing_gd.
Warning: No success on command[/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site]
CPAN: YAML loaded ok (v0.90)
  LDS/GD-2.53.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Make had some problems, won't test
Running make install
  Make had some problems, won't install
Could not read metadata file. Falling back to other methods to determine prerequisites
Failed during this command:
 LDS/GD-2.53.tar.gz                           : writemakefile NO '/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site' returned status 512
<-

I tryed to install "libgd 2.0.28 or higher" but don't find this in "yum".

locate libgd (shows):

/usr/lib64/libgd.so.2
/usr/lib64/libgd.so.2.0.0

Does anyone know an advice?

Comment: found it ...


activate the "RHEL Server Optional" software channel on your system in the rhn

Answer (score 2):

Many perl modules are available already built and packaged for RHEL and derivatives such as CentOS. In the case of perl-GD, it seems it is available in the CentOS in the base repo even though it is not in the RHEL repo.

However you can still use the Centos repo by adding it to your yum configuration. Create a file `/etc/yum.repos.d/cantos.repo` containing:

```
[centos]
name=CentOS $releasever - $basearch
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos-6/6/os/$basearch/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=0
```

After which you should be able to install perl-GD

```
yum install --enablerepo centos perl-GD
```

It looks as though the current version of perl-GD for centos is 2.44.

If you do need a newer version that that, you will either need to find a 3rd party yum repo which has the later version of libgd available, or compile it from source. In a quick google I could not find the former, so I would recommend you download the [latest source package](http://libgd.bitbucket.org/) and install that.

Comment: yum install perl-GD -y
...
No package perl-GD available.

Comment: thx for your answer! i wait a little more for more answers ... when there are no other, i do it like that ...

Comment: @user3518279 sorry, I tested on a centos box but I did not check that rhel had the package. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

You need the package `gd-devel` then rebuild the GD module.