# cannot load perl module GD

Tags: perl, gd

I'm trying to install the GD module (v2.56).  I can create the make file successfully using 'perl Makefile.PL' and then 'make' it but when I run 'make test' I get the following error:-

```
t/Polyline.t .. Can't locate loadable object for module GD in @INC (@INC contains: /root/.cpan/build/GD-2.56/blib/lib /root/.cpan/build/GD-2.56/blib/arch /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.22.0/x86_64-linux /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.22.0 /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.22.0/x86_64-linux /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.22.0 .) at /root/.cpan/build/GD-2.56/blib/lib/GD/Polyline.pm line 45.
Compilation failed in require at /root/.cpan/build/GD-2.56/blib/lib/GD/Polyline.pm line 45.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /root/.cpan/build/GD-2.56/blib/lib/GD/Polyline.pm line 45.
Compilation failed in require at t/Polyline.t line 10.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/Polyline.t line 10.
t/Polyline.t .. Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
```

I've checked and confirm that GD.pm (28 Oct 2014) is in the Perl INC path and I have gd, gd-devel, gdbm and gdbm-devel all installed

The server is Centos 6, perl is v 5.22.0 and gd is v2.0.35.

1. What am I doing wrong and how do I put it right?
2. Is there an alternative (other than Image::Magick which I also cannot get installed)?

Comment: Do you have `libgd-devel` installed?

Comment: Did you try installing a [prebuilt version](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22982069/293652)?

Comment: 1.  No, I don't have libgd-devel installed.  Yum list reports that no such package is available.  I do, however have both gd and gd-devel installed.

Comment: 2.  I already have perl-GD-2.44-3 installed

Comment: `libgd2-devel` maybe?

Comment: Nop, according to yum list, there is no package libgd anything

However libgd.so.2 (and 3) is in my /usr/lib64 directory (and in /usr/local/lib64)

Answer (score 0):

I eventually got this sorted out by putting a whole lot of debugging comments in GD.pm.

It transpires that it was failing because if couldn't load GD::Polygon::delete in spite of the fact that GD::Polygon was there, having been installed using CPAN.

Once I had re-installed GD::Polygon it all worked as it should do.